# Prove: $S_n^\perp=\{f_A:A\in A_n\}$ and $A_n^\perp=\{f_A : A\in S_n\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and for all $A\in V$ consider 
$f_A:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_A(B)=tr(AB)$

Let $S_n$ be the subspace of $V$ of symmetric matrices and $A_n$ be the subspace of $V$ of antisymmetric matrices.

Prove:
$S_n^\perp=\{f_A:A\in A_n\}$ and $A_n^\perp=\{f_A : A\in S_n\}$

Con someone give me a hint of how solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $A$ is antisymmetric and $B$ is symmetric, you can show directly that $tr(AB)=0$. Have you tried this? The properties you need are invariance of the trace under transpose and cyclic permutation of the arguments.

Comment: A slightly stronger statement is needed, that if $A$ is antisymmetric then $tr(AB)=0$ iff $B$ is symmetric, and vice versa.

Comment: Yes. Proving this much is a good start. Since the OP had not posted any progress so far and wanted a hint, this seemed about right.